# Classify elements of a numpy array using a second array as reference

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Let's say I have an array with a finite amount of unique values. Say

```
data = array([30, 20, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 10, 30])
```

And I also have a reference array with all the unique values found in `data`, without repetitions and in a particular order. Say

```
reference = array([20, 10, 30])
```

And I want to create an array with the same shape than `data` containing as values the indices in the `reference` array where each element in the `data` array is found.

In other words, having `data` and `reference`, I want to create an array `indexes` such that the following holds.

```
data = reference[indexes]
```

A suboptimal approach to compute `indexes` would be using a for loop, like this

```
indexes = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=int)
for i in range(data.size):
    indexes[i] = np.where(data[i] == reference)[0]
```

but I'd be surprised there is not a *numpythonic* (and thus faster!) way to do this... Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Uhm... I think I wasn't clear with that in the question, sorry... The `reference` array is expected to be way smaller than the `data` so that the main thing I needed to optimize was the loop through all the values in `data`...  Still, it's true I should think about the dictionaries more often that I do! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have `data` and `reference` as -

```
In [375]: data
Out[375]: array([30, 20, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 10, 30])

In [376]: reference
Out[376]: array([20, 10, 30])
```

For a moment, let us consider a sorted version of `reference` -

```
In [373]: np.sort(reference)
Out[373]: array([10, 20, 30])
```

Now, we can use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find out the position of each `data` element in this sorted version, like so -

```
In [378]: np.searchsorted(np.sort(reference), data, side='left')
Out[378]: array([2, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2], dtype=int64)
```

If we run the original code, the expected output turns out to be -

```
In [379]: indexes
Out[379]: array([2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 2])
```

As can be seen, the `searchsorted` output is fine except the `0's` in it must be `1s` and `1's` must be changed to `0's`. Now, we had taken into computation, the sorted version of `reference`. So, to do the `0's` to `1's` and vice versa changes, we need to bring in the indices used for sorting `reference`, i.e. `np.argsort(reference)`. That's basically it for a vectorized no-loop or no-dict approach! So, the final implementation would look something like this -

```
# Get sorting indices for reference
sort_idx = np.argsort(reference)

# Sort reference and get searchsorted indices for data in reference
pos = np.searchsorted(reference[sort_idx], data, side='left')

# Change pos indices based on sorted indices for reference
out = np.argsort(reference)[pos]
```

---

Runtime tests -

```
In [396]: data = np.random.randint(0,30000,150000)
     ...: reference = np.unique(data)
     ...: reference = reference[np.random.permutation(reference.size)]
     ...: 
     ...: 
     ...: def org_approach(data,reference):
     ...:     indexes = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=int)
     ...:     for i in range(data.size):
     ...:         indexes[i] = np.where(data[i] == reference)[0]
     ...:     return indexes
     ...: 
     ...: def vect_approach(data,reference):
     ...:     sort_idx = np.argsort(reference)
     ...:     pos = np.searchsorted(reference[sort_idx], data, side='left')       
     ...:     return sort_idx[pos]
     ...: 

In [397]: %timeit org_approach(data,reference)
1 loops, best of 3: 9.86 s per loop

In [398]: %timeit vect_approach(data,reference)
10 loops, best of 3: 32.4 ms per loop
```

Verify results -

```
In [399]: np.array_equal(org_approach(data,reference),vect_approach(data,reference))
Out[399]: True
```

Comment: Yeap! nice and fast method! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the data once to map the data values onto indexes. The quickest way to do that is to look up the value indexes in a dictionary. So you need to create a dictionary from values to indexes first.

Here's a complete example:

```
import numpy

data = numpy.array([30, 20, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 10, 30])
reference = numpy.array([20, 10, 30])
reference_index = dict((value, index) for index, value in enumerate(reference))
indexes = [reference_index[value] for value in data]
assert numpy.all(data == reference[indexes])
```

This will be faster than the `numpy.where` approach because `numpy.where` will do a linear, O(n), search while the dictionary approach uses a hashtable to find the index in O(1) time.

Comment: Nice! this applies makes sense when the `reference` array is not much smaller than the `data` array... In my case `reference` is way smaller, and `data` is large... It's true that my for loop example doesn't take this into account... something like `for i in range(reference.size): indexes[data==reference[i]] = i` would be faster if `data.size >>> reference.size`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([30, 20, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, 30, 20, 20, 30, 30, 10, 30])
reference = {20:0, 10:1, 30:2}
indexes = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=int)

for i in xrange(data.size):
    indexes[i] = reference[data[i]]
```

A dictionary lookup is significantly faster. The use of `xrange` also helped marginally.

Using timeit:

Original: 4.01297836938

This version: 1.30972428591